# Getting music NOT purchased from iTunes to show up on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, import, music.app

I have an iPhone but just recently bought an iPod. I want to put all my songs on the iPod and just have my favorites on my iPhone but all that seems to show up on my iPhone are the songs i bought from iTunes. How do i get the cd's i imported to show up on my iPhone? I can see them when the phone is plugged into the computer but once i unplug and look up the songs on the phone there are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select what music, for example, playlists, songs, artists or albums to sync to the iphone, please follow this apple support document

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201253

Comment: It is always best to include the relevant details behind a link. Links rot, but information copied in to your answer does not.